# Pointcut for methods with a specific annotation that override methods of an interface

Tags: java, aop, aspectj, aspect

Please consider the following setup:

```java
public interface IVehicle {
    public void start() {}  
    public void move() {}  
    public void stop() {}
}
```

```java
public class RaceCar implements IVehicle {
  @Override
  @Authenticated(Role.Pilot)
  public void start() { /* Logic to start the car. */ }  
  @Override
  @Authenticated(Role.Pilot)
  public void move() { /* Logic to move the car. */ }  
  @Override
  @Authenticated(Role.Pilot)
  public void stop() { /* Logic to the stop car. */ }
}
```

```java
public class RacingApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        IVehicle raceCar = new RaceCar();
        raceCar.start();
        raceCar.move();
        raceCar.stop();        
    }  
}
```

I need to get all calls to methods of RaceCar, that have the annotation @Authenticated, made inside the RacingApp class. The problem is that the calls are made to the interface IVehicle and not to the class RaceCar itself. Through polymorphism the methods are inferred to be from the RaceCar class at run time.

I have tried many pointcuts but I have not been able to achieve this yet. My best pointcut so far, in my opinion, is the following:

```java
@Pointcut("call(@Authenticated * IVehicle+.*(..)) && within(RacingApp)")
```

I think that I am pretty close but I can't seem to get this to work. Does anyone know how this can be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first, a little correction: In `IVehicle` the methods must not have bodies but semicolons after their declarations and the `public` for each method is superfluous because all methods declared in interfaces are public by definition. So it should look like this to at least make it compile:

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

public interface IVehicle {
  void start();
  void move();
  void stop();
}
```

In order to make your example compile for me I also recreated the other helper classes like this so as go get a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (which I think should have been your job, BTW):

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

public enum Role {
  Pilot, Passenger
}
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface Authenticated {
  Role value();
}
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

public class RaceCar implements IVehicle {
  @Override
  @Authenticated(Role.Pilot)
  public void start() {
    System.out.println("Starting");
  }

  @Override
  @Authenticated(Role.Pilot)
  public void move() {
    System.out.println("Moving");
  }

  @Override
  @Authenticated(Role.Pilot)
  public void stop() {
    System.out.println("Stopping");
  }
}
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

public class RacingApp {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    IVehicle raceCar = new RaceCar();
    raceCar.start();
    raceCar.move();
    raceCar.stop();
  }
}
```

Concerning your aspect, there is a detail that keeps it from functioning: When intercepting a `call()` to an interface method, the JVM and AspectJ only know that the interface does not have the annotations you are filtering with. Due to polymorphism, as you already mentioned, only during `execution()` it is clear which concrete implementing class's methods are executed.

Please also note that if you do not use native AspectJ syntax but the tedious annotation-driven @AspectJ style, you need to use fully qualified class names (i.e. incl. packages) in order to make your pointcuts match. For example:

```java
package de.scrum_master.aspect;

import org.aspectj.lang.JoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Before;

@Aspect
public class VehicleActionInterceptor {
  @Before("execution(@de.scrum_master.app.Authenticated * de.scrum_master.app.IVehicle+.*(..))")
  public void beforeAction(JoinPoint thisJoinPoint) {
    System.out.println(thisJoinPoint);
  }
}
```

This yields the following console output when running the driver application:

```
execution(void de.scrum_master.app.RaceCar.start())
Starting
execution(void de.scrum_master.app.RaceCar.move())
Moving
execution(void de.scrum_master.app.RaceCar.stop())
Stopping
```

If you want to do something with the annotation, you can also bind it to a parameter:

```java
package de.scrum_master.aspect;

import org.aspectj.lang.JoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Before;

import de.scrum_master.app.Authenticated;

@Aspect
public class VehicleActionInterceptor {
  @Before("execution(* de.scrum_master.app.IVehicle+.*(..)) && @annotation(authenticated)")
  public void beforeAction(JoinPoint thisJoinPoint, Authenticated authenticated) {
    System.out.println(thisJoinPoint + " -> " + authenticated);
  }
}
```

Now the output becomes:

```
execution(void de.scrum_master.app.RaceCar.start()) -> @de.scrum_master.app.Authenticated(value=Pilot)
Starting
execution(void de.scrum_master.app.RaceCar.move()) -> @de.scrum_master.app.Authenticated(value=Pilot)
Moving
execution(void de.scrum_master.app.RaceCar.stop()) -> @de.scrum_master.app.Authenticated(value=Pilot)
Stopping
```

The same aspect in more elegant native syntax and without the need to use fully qualified class names because you can use imports:

```java
package de.scrum_master.aspect;

import de.scrum_master.app.IVehicle;
import de.scrum_master.app.Authenticated;

public aspect VehicleActionInterceptor {
  before(Authenticated authenticated) : execution(* IVehicle+.*(..)) && @annotation(authenticated) {
    System.out.println(thisJoinPoint + " -> " + authenticated);
  }
}
```

---

**Update:** The OP asked how to limit joinpoint matching to only those executions which result from calls made by a certain class. The solution is to combine the `execution()` pointcut with a control clow pointcut like `cflow(call(...) && within(ClassOfInterest))`.

But first let us extend out test case with a little more log output and a second application class because we need a negative test case:

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

public class RacingApp {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("=== Racing app ===");
    IVehicle raceCar = new RaceCar();
    raceCar.start();
    raceCar.move();
    raceCar.stop();
    AnotherApp.main(args);
  }
}
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

public class AnotherApp {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("=== Another app ===");
    IVehicle raceCar = new RaceCar();
    raceCar.start();
    raceCar.move();
    raceCar.stop();
  }
}
```

Now we extend our aspect:

```java
package de.scrum_master.aspect;

import de.scrum_master.app.IVehicle;
import de.scrum_master.app.Authenticated;
import de.scrum_master.app.RacingApp;

public aspect VehicleActionInterceptor {
  before(Authenticated authenticated) :
    execution(* IVehicle+.*(..)) && @annotation(authenticated) &&
    cflow(call(* IVehicle+.*(..)) && within(RacingApp))
  {
    System.out.println(thisJoinPoint + " -> " + authenticated);
  }
}
```

The log output now becomes:

```
=== Racing app ===
execution(void de.scrum_master.app.RaceCar.start()) -> @de.scrum_master.app.Authenticated(value=Pilot)
Starting
execution(void de.scrum_master.app.RaceCar.move()) -> @de.scrum_master.app.Authenticated(value=Pilot)
Moving
execution(void de.scrum_master.app.RaceCar.stop()) -> @de.scrum_master.app.Authenticated(value=Pilot)
Stopping
=== Another app ===
Starting
Moving
Stopping
```

Et voilà!

Comment: thanks for your answer. I'm sorry that my example wasn't very practical, I'll keep that in mind next time I ask a question. Regarding my question, the reason I wanted to use call() instead of execution() is because I wanted to filter where the call is being made. So, for instances, if I had another class that has the exact same code that is inside the main method, execution() would catch both the calls from that class and calls from my App class, which is something I don't want. Is it possible to join call() and execution() together to filter where the calls are being made?

Comment: Yes, of course, see my update. But please note that `cflow()` is not evaluated during compilation but dynamically during runtime, i.e. more joinpoints are woven and there is a slight performance penalty. But maybe you do not even notice, it depends on how often the joinpoints in question are called.